# Setting datagrid cell background colour wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` whose cell background colour must be of 2 kinds.

1. Gray, if the cell has no value
2. White(Default), if the cell has any value

I wrote the code below to achieve this functionality, but it doesn't work.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<DataGrid CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}">
```

Can anyone please explain why?

Comment: Have you set background local value to `White`?

Comment: Not required...default is white only. Edited comment!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is happening, because the `Content` of `DataGridCell` is a `TextBlock` (Or a `TextBox` when the cell is editing). So even an empty cell contains an empty `TextBlock` (`TextBox`), i.e. `HasContent` property never becomes `false`.

This should work if you do not use custom template with your cells:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content.Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"  Value="" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: So how to achieve the functionality mentioned?

Comment: @user1603970 I believe `DataTrigger` + `IValueConverter` can do the trick, but not for sure. Im working on than now.

Comment: @user1603970 Solved. `IValueConverter` is not needed.